# I'm not geting the right results from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

I have this strored procedure that I use to get the sum of Amount from 3 tables.

The problem is that I'm using Linq to Sql and when I put this procedure on my .dbml file, it has a 
ISingleResult(GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReportResult) and I can't get the sums I want.

I'm receiving an empty ReceivablesSurplus list.

Any ideas?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReport]
    @ID INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

          SELECT    SUM(RB.[Amount])
    FROM    [DBO].[ReceivablesSurplus] RB
    WHERE   RB.[Cycle] = @ID

    SELECT  SUM(DL.[Amount])
    FROM    [DBO].[DilutionsSurplus] DL
    WHERE   DL.[Cycle] = @ID

    SELECT  SUM(AC.[Amount])
    FROM    [DBO].[AccountablesSurplus] AC
    WHERE   AC.[Cycle] = @ID
END
```

this is my .dbml code

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReport")]
        public ISingleResult<GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReportResult> GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReport([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ID", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iD)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), iD);
            return ((ISingleResult<GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReportResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

Comment: can you see the sql that its running?

Comment: is your sproc giving proper results when run independently?

Comment: @AnandPhadke yes, it gives the results I want.

Comment: Just as @DanielA.White stated you'll need to see the SQL that's running using a profiler tool. However, I would also highly recommend [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) if you're not too far along in your project. You build POCO objects, and it simply extends the IDbConnection interface with extension methods. It's also ***very*** fast.

Comment: What does a `GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReportResult` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use `.ToList()` on the value (as `ISingleResult` implements `IEnumerable`) to the calling line of code, and then you can get at the separate result sets that are returned from the sproc.

e.g

```
var results = dataContext.GetSurplusDataForConsolidationReport(123).ToList<int>(); // list of sums
```